# How do you buy premium cylinders?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I'm on the last chapter in the game, have maxxed my salvage rank and dev level for every city (except one). I can't seem to find a place to buy premium cylinders. I've heard that they can be bought before the last chapter and not at an A rank salvager too. It seems the common denominator is that you stop being able to buy them at some point, but I can't confirm that since I've never been able to.

How do you buy premium cylinders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Expansion Pass adds a way to craft them.

First, you have to do the "M.I.A. Nopon" quest which starts in Uraya.

Next, bring 4 Gold Cylinders, 2 Silver Cylinders, and a Chain of Keys (salvaged in Gormott) to Budada in Goldmouth (on the flight deck level).

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/7rxosc/psa_you_can_have_premium_cylinders_crafted_after/)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/204208-xenoblade-chronicles-2/76097219), premium cylinders may randomly appear once you visit cylinder shop (long rest may be required).

**Update:**

I've actually got them by myself. Same as in thread above - just long-rest in Torigoth until you get them in cylinder shop. Seems to be completely random - previous time I haven't got them for 1 hour of long resting, and now I did less than 10 times to get this. Screen as proof:

[image]

Comment: I have seen this, but I've been unable to get it to work myself after resting for a similar amount of times.

Comment: Just got them, and have proof. Answer updated. Keep trying.

Comment: Stupidly frustrating, but so it goes. I was hoping a more reliable method would come along.

Answer (score 1):

I've beaten the game, maxed all development levels, and gotten my salvager rank to A, and now they appear at every shop all the time.  When I was at salvager rank B, I never saw a single shop with them.

Comment: Please use the inn a few times and confirm if this is still the case. This could be a duplicate of the other answer by @lentinant, you just might be in that state where it works, instead of the one where it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, after about 7 rests they disappeared.  I hardly ever use an inn, so that may be why they lasted so long.  So the moral of the story is that if these pop up, try to get all your salvaging out of the way without going to an inn for a while.

Answer (score -1):

From what I heard there is a NPC somewhere that tells you that they are very rare and barely ever sold so I suggest just fast travel to different titans and check the stores there and you might be able to find some

Comment: This is unfortunately not really helpful. I've been to every shop in the game. I've read that you can get them from any salvage shop if you rest a few times and check. I haven't been able to validate that personally, and I'm looking for a reliable way to buy them.